# How to get only List of IDs of JSON Objects?

Tags: java, json, rest

I have some problem. I get a Response from my RESTful WebServices with JSON Objects in a list. For example:

I get a List of these elements and I want just to get the id from the benutzerId.

```
[{
  "benutzerId": {
      "benutzername": "Nenzema",
      "geschlecht": "m",
      "id": 1,
      "nachname": "Marinovic",
      "passwort": "test1",
      "vorname": "Nenad"
    },
    "hochzeitId": {
      "id": 4
    },
    "id": 1,
    "isbrautbenutzer": true
  }, {
    "benutzerId": {
      "benutzername": "dnikolic",
      "geschlecht": "m",
      "id": 2,
      "nachname": "Nikolic",
      "passwort": "test2",
      "vorname": "Djordje"
    },
    "hochzeitId": {
      "id": 4
    },
    "id": 4,
    "isbrautbenutzer": false
  }]
```

I already made it, to get just the benutzer, but I dont know how to return a json Object where only the id is in this object, because I dont want to send the whole data to the requester.

```
[{
  "benutzername": "Nenzema",
  "geschlecht": "m",
  "id": 1,
  "nachname": "Marinovic",
  "passwort": "test1",
  "vorname": "Nenad"
}, {
  "benutzername": "dnikolic",
  "geschlecht": "m",
  "id": 2,
  "nachname": "Nikolic",
  "passwort": "test2",
  "vorname": "Djordje"
}]
```

So my aim would be to get something like this:

```
[{
  "id": 1
}, {
"id": 2
}]
```

This is the query for the first list:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Hochzeitsplan.findByBenutzerId", 
query = "SELECT h FROM Hochzeitsplan h WHERE h.benutzerId.id = :benutzerId"),
```

These two queries I also tested, but its not working..

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Hochzeitsplan.getHochzeitsuserByHochzeitsId",
query = "SELECT DISTINCT h.benutzerId FROM Hochzeitsplan h WHERE h.hochzeitId.id = :hochzeitId"),

@NamedQuery(name = "Hochzeitsplan.findBenutzerIdByHochzeitsId", 
query = "SELECT h.benutzerId.id FROM Hochzeitsplan h WHERE h.hochzeitId.id = :hochzeitId"),
```

This is the method I use for getting the Response with the List:

```
@GET
@Path("/hochzeitIDneu={hochzeitId}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getListByHochzeitID(@PathParam("hochzeitId") Integer hochzeitId) {
    Query query=em.createNamedQuery("Hochzeitsplan.findByHochzeitId",Hochzeitsplan.class)
                  .setParameter("hochzeitId", hochzeitId);
    List<Hochzeitsplan> a =query.getResultList();

    a.sort(new Comparator<Hochzeitsplan>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Hochzeitsplan o1, Hochzeitsplan o2) 
        {
            return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
        }
    });

    if(a.isEmpty()) {
       ErrorManager error1 = new ErrorManager();
       return Response.status(400).entity(error1.getError(Enums.ErrorResponses.NORESULTS)).build();
    } else {
       return Response.ok(a.toArray(new Hochzeitsplan[a.size()])).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JsonPath Evaluator like Jayway Jsonpath.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path

Your json path can be something like this

```
$[*]['benutzerId'].id
```

This would generate output something like 
[
   1,
   2
]

U can try this online https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer, have I to put this then in the  query in the select statement? Select $[*]['benutzerId'].id from ... ?