# How to get List of IDs available in Objects of sub-array

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

StackOverflow community, I have a problem similar to this dude
[How to get only List of IDs of JSON Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357060/how-to-get-only-list-of-ids-of-json-objects)

but I need to do it with a MongoDB query because I need to query a lot of Data.

I have 1 Object like this:

```
{ 
"_id": ObjectId(".."),
"data": 
 [

    {
      customId : 22,
      customArr:[
           321,
           123
      ]
    },
    {
      customId : 33,
      customArr:[
           123
      ]
    },
    {
      customId : 22,
      customArr:[
      ]
    }
 ]
}
```

(ofc there is more data, but only this is important for this)
Problem:
I don't know how to get lists like this:

> [ 22, 33 ]

and

> [ 123, 321 ]

I need these lists to Compute my data, but I am currently completely unable to compute anything.
I can't change my structure, because I already accumulated a LOT of data in this format and it would break my whole application.

I am using MongoDB 3.4 so all the 3.2 aggregate updates are usable,
but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone link me a Documentation I need to read to be able to Complete this task? Or give any hints witch MongoDB functions I need for this?

thank you for your help in Advance, I will post my Solution if I find one

Comment: You can try [**this**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qm46f6Ybh5_) `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      customId: {
        $setUnion: "$data.customId"
      },
      customArr: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$this.customArr",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: omg thanks this works perfect, i feel so silly i had a query similar to this once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "customId": { "$setUnion": "$data.customId" },
    "customArr": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$data",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$this.customArr", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```